# CSS 3 hide element when :target is set to something else - show when it is blank?

Tags: css, css-selectors, target

Just trying to see if there is a pure CSS3 solution to this idea I came up with.

Basically, if the user navigates to `http://example.com`, I'd like to show an element on my page, say `<section id="main" />`. If the visit `http://example.com/#pics`, though, I'd like to show a photo gallery.

I know that this can be done with JQuery, but I'm trying to do as much as I can with CSS3, this is just an experimental site, so browser support isn't a priority, but I am interested in fallbacks.

Comment: I don't believe this can be done with pure CSS. You won't be able to select `#main` only when none of the sections is `:target`, without the use of classes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This answer assumes you are selecting elements with the class "hideme". Adjust as needed for your case.

Any kind of "if not" can be done with the `:not()` psuedo-class. In this case:

```
.hideme:not(:target) {display: none;}
```

However, browser support for this is very low, so instead you should do something like this:

```
selector {do something}
selector:target {cancel the something}
```

Now, this is a little tricky with `display` because different elements have different defaults, but it `visibility` is an option for you:

```
.hideme {visibility: hidden;}
.hideme:target {visibility: visible;}
```

Alternatively, or additionally, you might be able to use `position:absolute` and `position:static` to remove the selected item from the flow of the document.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=:not  says that everything but <ie8 supports it css3 selectors in general

Comment: Browser support is a non-issue given the use of `:target` in the question. No browser in existence supports `:target` without supporting `:not()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the :target selector and the :not selector

you can do something along the lines of

```
div:not(:target){
  display:none
}

#main:target {
   display:block;
}

#pics:target {
    display:block;
}
```

Ref:
http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/ section 6.6.7 is the :not selector (no target from their file)

and

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo

Comment: The problem with this is that if there's no hash fragment, `#main` will never display.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn this is true. As far as I know, however, there's no way to specify a "default" through CSS alone.  This is where a javascript framework/browser history manager is much more suited to this job.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code in multiple containers, so you can use the target pseudo-class to select every element you need.

### Example

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="100" version="1.1">
<style>

/* hide elements by default */
.hide {
  display: none;
}
/* show the elements by target */
#one:target .one,
#two:target .two {
display: block;
}

/* BONUS: using this technique, you can select other elements */
#one:target .default,
#two:target .default {
display: none;
}

/* some colors... */
.one {
fill: red;
}
.two {
fill: yellow;
}


</style>
<g id="one">
<g id="two">
   <rect width="200" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="green"/>
      <circle class="hide one" cx="50" cy="50" r="20"></circle>
      <circle class="hide two" cx="100" cy="50" r="20"></circle>
      <circle class="default" cx="150" cy="50" r="20"></circle>
</g>
</g>

</svg>
```

Maybe it's not an elegant solution, but it works.